# SO: adding comments with iPhone is a slow process

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, comments, javascript

The input of a comment on SO with the iPhone is very slow.

It seems there is a flaw in the Javascript, either too complex for the iPhone, or buggy?

(using iPhone 4)

Comment: Nobody else encountered the same problem?

Comment: I have the same problem, it's pretty annoying. I'm on OS 4.1, and it happens on any stack exchange site. There's also a hard to reproduce bug that causes the backspace key to erase two letters instead of one, which is probably related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completed; it had to do with adding and removing classes (on keypress event) to the "x characters left" span. Excruciatingly slow on the iPhone, but fine on the iPad.

We now only change the class when the class needs to change, not on every keypress.